# Java Polymorphism and Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I am working on a system which requires performance at its peak and i am stuck in one scenario whose solution i want to ask.

Here is my code

```
public interface ILoad {
    public void loadData();
}
```

```
public class ClassOne implements ILoad {
    @Override
    public void loadData() {
        System.out.println("CLASS ONE LOADING DATA ");
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassTwo implements ILoad {
    @Override
    public void loadData() {
        System.out.println("CLASS TWO LOADING DATA");
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    load(new ClassOne());
    load(new ClassTwo());
}

public static void load(Object o){
    ILoad ref = (ILoad) o;
    ref.loadData();
}
```

As you can see in above case there are no `if else` or `switch` conditions all the code is executed using interfaces by reference which is super fast when it comes to programming.

My question is for instance my interface has two methods `loadData()` and `loadRecord()`

Now if I want to execute these two methods just as on above example how can I do this? one way is make a separate class, second way reflection and introspection. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: One more thing i dont want to use any conditions in this case as those are bad for performance for systems whose responce time is in nano seconds.

Comment: if you put class one and class two objects in an array, just call loadData on each object. java will inherently figure out which should be executed

Comment: no this is not my question. i am saying for instance i have two methods which my interface contains one is loadData second is loadRecord. i want to call sometimes loadData and sometimes loadRecord. i am my self trying to do this by reflection but no luck

Comment: @UmerKiani What is the criteria for choosing?

Comment: Say initial on Launch it should call loadData now whenever user click on a button it should call loadRecord.

Comment: well that just sounds like a simple if/else

Comment: I don't understand the question. Also, if the absolute fastest performance is the goal, reflection is almost never the answer. You'd need to prove to me that an `if` statement would *truly* be a bottleneck.

Comment: agreed Dave thats why i am not using Reflection. hang on let me edit this code fast and post what i want

Comment: Jeff it cant be done using if else because there are more than 200 classes it is not possible to condition them as all those will have different criteria

Comment: Depending on what those methods truly do, isn't putting the `loadData` in the constructor of your classes resolve the issue? Then in the "main" you only call `loadRecord`. Have a look to [Lazy Initialization](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) also. Still I'm not really sure what you're asking...

Comment: got the solution it is as simple as passing method to execute in paramets of load method and works like charm

Comment: no reflaction etc required just simple pass which method you want to execute

Comment: Why not using handlers say ``onLoad`` event execute ``loadData()`` otherwise ``loadRecord()`` using Events and Listeners should be a very helpful

Comment: If you really need super fast performance, you probably shouldn't use Java.

Comment: It's probably cache misses and missed branch predictions that will slow down your code a lot more than just conditionals... Conditionals by themselves aren't bad when you have a good predictor and predictable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using polymorphism properly if you have to cast.

How about something like this?

```
public static interface ILoadData {

    public void loadData();
}

public static interface ILoadRecord {

    public void loadRecord();
}

public static interface ILoadEither extends ILoadData, ILoadRecord {
}

public static class ClassOne implements ILoadData {

    @Override
    public void loadData() {
        System.out.println("CLASS ONE LOADING DATA ");
    }
}

public static class ClassTwo implements ILoadData {

    @Override
    public void loadData() {
        System.out.println("CLASS TWO LOADING DATA");
    }
}

public static class ClassThree implements ILoadRecord {

    @Override
    public void loadRecord() {
        System.out.println("CLASS THREE LOADING RECORD");
    }
}

public static class ClassFour implements ILoadRecord, ILoadData {

    @Override
    public void loadRecord() {
        System.out.println("CLASS FOUR LOADING RECORD");
    }

    @Override
    public void loadData() {
        System.out.println("CLASS FOUR LOADING DATA");
    }
}

public static class ClassFive implements ILoadEither {

    @Override
    public void loadRecord() {
        System.out.println("CLASS FIVE LOADING RECORD");
    }

    @Override
    public void loadData() {
        System.out.println("CLASS FIVE LOADING DATA");
    }
}

public static void load(ILoadData o) {
    o.loadData();
}

public static void load(ILoadRecord o) {
    o.loadRecord();
}

public static void load(ILoadEither o) {
    o.loadRecord();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    load(new ClassOne());
    load(new ClassTwo());
    load(new ClassThree());
    load((ILoadData)new ClassFour());
    load((ILoadRecord)new ClassFour());
    load(new ClassFive());
}
```

Here we have multiple `static load` methods, each taking a parameter of a different interface but the compiler can decide at compile time which to use, unless it is ambiguous, in which case you need some other trick - I use casting here as it is simple but you would be better to use an adaptor of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you doing this:

```
   public static void load(ILoad o){ // both classes implement Iload. using Object here gives a chance for anything to come here.
    o.loadData();
}
```

Comment: because this is just an example code in my actual code there are difference interfaces passes and those types are determined using generics and refernces

Comment: @UmerKiani - do you ahve a common interface which is extended by your *other* interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question, but isn't enough the following code?

```
public interface ILoad {

   public void loadData();
   public void loadRecord();
}

public class ClassOne implements ILoad{

   @Override
   public void loadData() {
      System.out.println("CLASS ONE LOADING DATA ");
   }

   @Override
   public void loadRecord() {
      System.out.println("CLASS ONE LOADING RECORD");
   }

}

public class ClassTwo implements ILoad{

   @Override
   public void loadData() {
      System.out.println("CLASS TWO LOADING DATA ");
   }

   @Override
   public void loadRecord() {
      System.out.println("CLASS TWO LOADING RECORD");
   }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   // TODO code application logic here
   load(new ClassOne());
   load(new ClassTwo());

   //new objects created here, instances can be created just once
   loadRecord(new ClassOne());
   loadRecord(new ClassTwo());
}

public static void load(ILoad l){
   ref.loadData();
}

public static void loadRecord(ILoad l){
   ref.loadRecord();
}
```